# The TCP/IP connection to the host port 1433 fails when reading to Azure DB from Apache Spark Databricks

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks

I am attempting to read from an Azure SQLDB but keep on getting error message

> The TCP/IP connection to the host
> cp-retbihydr8config.database.windows.net.database.windows.net, port
> 1433 has failed

I have setup the following connection variables as follows:

```
DBUser = 'techadmin'
DBPword = 'xxxxxxxx'
DBServer = 'xxxxxx.database.windows.net'
DBDatabase = 'xxxxxx'
```

The code to read from the database is as follows:

```
def readFromDb(processId, query):
  try:
    jdbcDF = (spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
      .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net;database={DBDatabase}")
      .option("user", DBUser)
      .option("query", query)
      .option("password", DBPword)
      .load()    
     )
    return jdbcDF
  except Exception as e:
    writeToLogs(processId,LogType.Error, EventType.FailReadFromDb, LogMessage.FailReadFromDb, errorType = ErrorType.FailReadFromDb)
    raise Error(f"{LogMessage.FailReadFromDb.value} ERROR: {e}")
  except:
    writeToLogs(processId,LogType.FailReadFromDb, EventType.FailReadFromDb, LogMessage.FailReadFromDb, errorType = ErrorType.FailReadFromDb)
    raise Error(f"{LogMessage.FailReadFromDb.value}")
```

When I test the function with the following code:

```
readFromDb(1,5)
```

I get the full error message:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net.database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: &#34;xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net.database.windows.net. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.&#34;
```

I 100% know the issue isn't with ip address connection because I can successfully write to the database using the following code:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxxx.windows.net:1433;database=xxxxxxxxxx;user=techadmin@cp-retbihydr8config;password=xxxxxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"


df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", 'UpdatedProducts') \
    .save()
```

I also get the error message if I use:

```
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DBDatabase};user={DBUser};password={DBPword};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
```

So, I don't know why I'm getting the error with the function (readFromDb) to read from the database? Or when I use:

```
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DBDatabase};user={DBUser};password={DBPword};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was passing in the wrong variable

I was passing in:

```
DBServer = 'xxxxxx.database.windows.net'
```

Whereas I should have just passed in:

```
DBServer = 'xxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL server on Azure is blocking all incoming connections until you explicitly allow them.  So you need to allow access to the [SQL server from the Databricks cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure) on the firewall. Another possibility is to use [service endpoint for SQL server](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-sql-database-now-generally-available/).

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for reaching out. Normally, I would have said you were 100% correct. But the fact that I can write to th database with ```jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxxx.windows.net:1433;database=xxxxxxxxxx;user=techadmin@cp-retbihydr8config;password=xxxxxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"``` would suggest it isn't a firewall issue. Also, I have explicitly allowed the ip address from Databricks to access the server

Comment: Don't forget, I have problems accessing the database using the function readFromDb() or when use the connection ```jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DBDatabase};user={DBUser};password={DBPword};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"```

Comment: Hi, for your information I'm seeing the additional error message which could give us a clue ```raise Py4JJavaError(
"An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
format(target_id, ".", name), value)```

Comment: It looks like the problem could be coming from format in the following: ```f"jdbc:sqlserver://{DBServer}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DBDatabase};user={DBUser};password={DBPword};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"```

Comment: sorry, missed the piece that you can connect other way

Comment: do you have any special characters in the Password? that aren't enabled in the URI. You can pass the user & password via options: `.option("user", "username").option("password", "password")`